# "no autovivication" pragma fails with grep in Perl

Tags: perl, autovivification

I am trying to turn off autovivication using the module: https://metacpan.org/pod/autovivification but it is failing for grep:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use feature 'say';
use autodie ':all';
use DDP;
no autovivification;

my %h = (
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
);
p %h; # pretty print the original hash
my @fake_keys = ('x', 'y', 'z');
if (grep {defined} @h{@fake_keys}) {
    say "found fake keys";
}
p %h; # show that 'x', 'y', & 'z' are added as undef keys
```

How can I turn off autovivication for grep?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution:

```
if (grep { defined($h{$_}) } @fake_keys) {
   say "found fake keys";
}
```

Explanation follows.

---

Autovivification, as used in the Perl documentation, is the creation of anon vars and references to them when an undefined scalar is dereferenced.

For example, autovivification dictates that `$x->[0]` is equivalent to `( $x //= [] )->[0]`.

For example, autovivification dictates that `$h{p}{q}` is equivalent to `( $h{p} //= {} )->{q}`.

There is no dereferencing in your code, so autovivifaction couldn't possibly occur in your code, so `no autovivification;` doesn't help.

---

What you have in your code is a hash element used as an lvalue. "lvalue" means assignable value. It's named after the fact that such expressions are usually found on the *l*eft of assignments.

```perl
  $h{key} = ...;
# ^^^^^^^
# lvalue
```

But they are also found elsewhere in Perl.

```perl
for ($h{key}) {
   # ^^^^^^^
   # lvalue
}
```

```perl
map { } $h{key}
      # ^^^^^^^
      # lvalue
```

```perl
grep { } $h{key}
       # ^^^^^^^
       # lvalue
```

```perl
some_sub($h{key});
       # ^^^^^^^
       # lvalue
```

This is because the block of each of looping constructs can modify the items being processed by modifying `$_`, and subs can modify their arguments my modifying the elements of `@_`.

```perl
for ($h{key}) {
   $_ = uc($_);                 # Modifies $h{key}
}
```

```perl
grep { $_ = uc($_) } $h{key}    # Modifies $h{key}  # Bad practice, but possible.
```

```perl
map { $_ = uc($_) } $h{key}     # Modifies $h{key}
```

```perl
sub some_sub {
   $_[0] = uc($_[0]);           # Modifies $h{key}
}

some_sub($h{$k});
```

For that to be possible, `$h{$k}` must exist before the loop body is entered or the sub is called.

```sh
$ perl -M5.010 -e'for ($h{key}) { }  say 0+keys(%h);'
1
```

Sub calls use expensive magic to avoid this.

```sh
$ perl -M5.010 -e'sub f { }  f($h{key});  say 0+keys(%h);'
0
```

But `grep` and `map` do not.

```sh
$ perl -M5.010 -e'grep { 1 } $h{key};  say 0+keys(%h);'
1
```

```sh
$ perl -M5.010 -e'map {; } $h{key};  say 0+keys(%h);'
1
```

Answer (score 7):

It's not `grep` but the aliasing of the values in your hash slice that causes this.

This has the same effect:

```
for (@h{@fake_keys}){
 my $t = $_;
}
```

You can work around it by copying the slice:

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use feature 'say';
use autodie ':all';
use DDP;

my %h = (
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
);
p %h; # pretty print the original hash
my @fake_keys = ('x', 'y', 'z');
if (grep {defined} @{[@h{@fake_keys}]}) {
    say "found fake keys";
}
p %h; # show that 'x', 'y', & 'z' are added as undef keys
```

Or access each value in the grep block like [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66160300/10667839) by Ikegami.

Comment: is there documentation on the aliasing that you speak of? Search engines aren't yielding what I wan.  Also, your solution doesn't even require the `no autovivication` module, which is great!

Comment: It's in `perldoc -fgrep`

Comment: That's a bad alternative. There's no reason to create an array