# Perl: How to grep with Hash Slices?

Tags: perl

I am trying to sort out defined parameters from a complex hash, using hash slices.  Hash slices are great because they avoid lots of `foreach` and `if defined` so they simplify syntax greatly.

However, I'm clearly not doing this correctly:

```
use DDP;
my %hash = (
    'a' => # first patient
        {
            'age' => 9,
            'BMI' => 20
        },
    'b' =>
        {
            'age' => 8
        }
);

my %defined_patients = grep {defined $hash{$_}{'age', 'BMI'}} keys %hash;
p %defined_patients;
```

The above code gives an empty hash, when I want it to return just patient `a`.

This question is similar to ["no autovivication" pragma fails with grep in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66156905/no-autovivication-pragma-fails-with-grep-in-perl) and I've based my code on it.

I've also tried

```
my @defined_patients = grep {defined $hash{$_}{'age', 'BMI'}} keys %hash;
```

but that doesn't work either.

How can I use hash slices to `grep` patients with the defined keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check that none of the target keys are undefined, you have to check separately. This greps for undefined values:

```
grep { ! defined } @{ $hash{$_} }{ qw(age BMI) }
```

Notice that the hash slice

```
@{ $hash{$_} }{ qw(age BMI) }
```

In v5.24, you can use [postfix dereferencing](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/) instead:

```
$hash{$_}->@{ qw(age BMI) }
```

But that `grep` has to fit in another one. Since you want the cases where all values are defined, you have to negate the result of the inner `grep`:

```
my @patients =
    grep { ! grep { ! defined } $hash{$_}->@{ qw(age BMI) } }
    keys %hash;
```

That's pretty ugly though. I'd probably do something simpler in a subroutine. This way you can handle any number of keys easily:

```
sub some_patients {
   my( $hash, $keys ) = @_;
   my @patient_keys;
   foreach my $key ( keys %$hash ) {
       next unless grep { ! defined } $hash{$key}->@{ @$keys };
       push $key, @patient_keys;
       }
   return @patient_keys;
   }
```

Now I simply call a subroutine instead of grokking multilevel greps:

```
my @patient_keys = some_patients( \%patients, [ qw(age BMI) ] );
```

Or, for something more targeted, maybe something like this that tests a particular sub-hash instead of the whole data structure:

```
sub has_defined_keys {
    my( $hash, $keys ) = @_;
    ! grep { ! defined } $hash->@{@$keys}
    }

my @target-keys = ...;
my @keys = grep { 
    has_defined_keys( $patients{$_}, \@target-keys )
    } keys %patients;
```

Either way, when things start getting a bit too complex, use a subroutine to give those things names so you can hide the code in favor of something short.